# Why {} is better candidate to be int than string for C++ overload resolution?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Overload resolution favours to consider {} as being of some fundamental type as opposed to some container.

For example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void foo(const std::string&) {std::cout << "string\n";}
void foo(int) {std::cout << "int\n";}

int main() { foo({}); }
```

That compiles without any diagnostics and outputs:

> int

https://godbolt.org/z/zETfrs5as

If to comment out the `int` overload then it works fine with `string`.

The question is why? For programmer's standpoint it can be confusing
illusion.

Comment: This is even more intresting: https://godbolt.org/z/a8W3GdEW4

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From [over.ics.list#9.2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/over.ics.list#9.2):

> if the initializer list has no elements, the implicit conversion sequence is the identity conversion. [ Example:
>
> ```
>  void f(int);
>
>  f( { } );               // OK: identity conversion
> ```
>
> — end example ]

Thus, the conversion from `{}` to `int` is an identity conversion, while `{}` to `const std::string&` is a user-defined conversion. And since the identity conversion is a better match, the overload corresponding to `int` will be chosen.

Comment: The compiler will fail if you add an other function with a basic type (float, long ...)

Comment: @HeeroYui Yes, as expected.