# Why is const char * overload chosen instead of std::string?

Tags: c++, overload-resolution

In this code:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
 
void my_function(const char* value)
{
    std::cout << "char *  " << (value ? value : "nullptr");
}

void my_function(const std::string &value)
{
    std::cout << "string";
}

int main()
{
    my_function({});
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/56bxzjM1M

The `const char *` overload is chosen, passing a `nullptr` pointer.  Can somebody explain why? I assume this is something weird with initializer lists? (By the way, this happens with `my_function(string value)` too, so it isn't the reference).

This caused a crash in our code because somebody added a `const char *` overload, causing the rare caller who passed `{}` to send in a `nullptr`.

Comment: Dupe: [Why {} is better candidate to be int than string for C++ overload resolution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72056424/why-is-better-candidate-to-be-int-than-string-for-c-overload-resolution/72057076#72057076)

Comment: @JasonLiam Thanks, I couldn't find that, I appreciate it.